# Issue while creating a user in azure SQL server

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

In my application I need to create a user with the email id in the azure Sql server. Eg:
**The email id is: xxxx@gmail.com
create user xxxx@gmail.com with password '123131'**

The user gets created but when I try to login with that user a message is shown.
Cannot open server "gmail.com" requested by the login. The login failed  [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO4UP.png)

The issue is with @. If I change it with some other character it works. Is there any alternative because I need to create user with the email id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

SSMS recognize @gmail.com as server name here, and the workaround is simple: Assuming your SQL database server name is **testserver**.database.windows.net and you have a user **username@gmail.com**, in SSMS you should specify the username as **username@gmail.com@testserver** and that would work. This should also applies to JDBC and ODBC connections as well.